# Query D6 db from D7 module

Tags: 7, migrations

I want to import a content type data from D6 db to D7. 
I have db in settings file like....

```
    /**
     * Database
     */
    $databases['default']['default'] = array(
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'database' => 'd7',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => 'root',
      'host' => 'localhost',
    );
    $databases['d6']['default'] = array(
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'database' => 'd6',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => 'root',
      'host' => 'localhost',
    );
```

I am trying to query nid's from D6 db from D7 module using db_query, but cant use node_load for D6 db then.

```
    function import_schools() {
      db_set_active($key = 'd6');

      $result = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE type = :type AND nid         = :nid", array(
        ':type' => 'classified',
        ':nid' => '77307',
      ));

      while ($record = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
        print_r($record);
        print_r(node_load($record['nid']));
      }

    }
```

How can I chang API from d7 to d6 on fly while switching db using db_set_active.

Comment: Drupal's API isn't swappable, if you want to use the D6 API you need to bootstrap a D6 site

Comment: How to switch between bootstraps while file is on D7 root dir.

Comment: You can't bootstrap D6 and D7 in the same request, too many identically named functions

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to Migrate D6 Content (Nodes) to D7 system then you can use [Drupal-to-Drupal data migration](https://drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d) module.

Project page says

> migrate_d2d provides a framework based on the Migrate API for
>   migrating content from Drupal 5, Drupal 6, or Drupal 7 sites into the
>   Drupal 7 site where it is installed.